# Non-real time simulation of overlapping repulsive balls

Tags: c++, collision-detection, simulation

I want to make a non-real time simulation of overlapping repulsive balls, initially in 2D and later in 3D.

First of all, consider a simple closed domain for simplicity. In practice, domains will be complex and irregular but always closed.

The balls on the boundaries are fixed and could be overlapping. A fixed ball duplicates itself to produce a free ball of the same size whenever no other ball overlaps it. Both fixed and free balls repel each other but fixed balls cannot move. Note that, duplicant ball should be sufficiently tilted to start repulsion. In elastic colliding balls case, after two balls collide they change direction with some velocity but in this case the balls can stop quickly once they stop overlapping. Free balls move until there is no motion or let's say we solve motion problem until convergence. Then each fixed ball produce a free ball again and this process goes on until no fixed ball can duplicate due to being overlapped by any other ball(s).

I think GPU (CUDA) would be faster to solve this problem but initially I am thinking to write on CPU. However, before proceeding to coding I would like to know "feasibility" of this work. That is, considering a million of balls, approximately how long it would take to simulate this or similar kind of problems in non-real time. For a million of balls, if solution time is in order of minutes, I will dive into the problem.

[image: Fig. 1]
[image: Fig. 2]
[image: Fig. 3]
[image: Fig. 4]
[image: Fig. 5]
[image: Fig. 6]
[image: Fig. 7]
[image: Fig. 8]
[image: Fig. 9]

[image]

Comment: And the question is? Anyway, this is far too broad. Dive into it and come back if yyou have a **specific** problem. See [ask].

Comment: Do you really imagine that someone can estimate the runtime of code you haven't written yet on unspecified hardware based only on a flow chart and a picture of some balls and boxes?

Comment: @talonmies: What I think is that in today's games there are a lot collision detections and this specific problem is nothing compared to them. Those developers will have an idea how long these processes take. Somehow I get answers to my questions on this or other platforms by the guys who know their field very well.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using Box2D for a prototype. Setting up your collision constraints to be 'soft' would give you about the kind of behavior you're showing in your diagrams.

As for simulating a million objects in real time, you're going to be working on a GPU.

Comment: Is it possible to continuously add balls to domain in Box2D?

Comment: Yes. See b2BodyDef for how you'd specify the objects and b2World's CreateBody to create an instance of a b2Body. I don't know anything about PhysX, but it might be the easiest way to do what you're trying on a GPU. (I seriously doubt you'll get 1M objects in real-time, anyway.)

Comment: With any physics engine, you're likely to see your above example create a perfect asterix. The trouble is that the forces on all objects will be perfectly symmetrical, so they'll all remain symmetrically aligned. You'll have to thwart this by introducing some randomness into the system. Doing so at the moment you insert the objects is probably your best bet. Another issue is that when you place an object, and it's already overlapping other objects, you'll inject tremendous, unwanted forces into your system. Try turning off new objects' dynamics while you slowly push them into the world.